# Why does .hgignore appears in my patches?

Tags: mercurial, hgignore, mercurial-queue

I use Mercurial Queues to work with patches.

There was no `.hgignore` initially.
I'm not sure if I first created an `MQ` patch and then created my `.hgignore` or the other way round.

(By "creating a patch" I mean `hg qnew patch_name -m "..."`)

Anyway, I made some *changes* to `.hgignore` after I created the `MQ` patch.

When I did `hg qrefresh; hg export qtip` I got the changed contents of `.hgignore` also in my patch.
So, tried adding an `.hgignore` entry to `.hgignore` itself. But that didn't work. The changes persisted.

So, I tried `hg forget .hgignore` and this made a bigger mess. It nows shows that I deleted .hgignore in my patch. Like so:

```
--- a/.hgignore
+++ /dev/null
- all 
- the lines of .hgignore
- the lines of .hgignore
```

How do I resolve this problem?
I just want `.hgignore` to be part of my local repo and help in not tracking some files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.hgignore is designed to be tracked by Mercurial ([doc](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html)).  The standard way to ignore files in local clone only is to use `ui.ignore` setting:

```
# .hg/hgrc
[ui]
ignore = /path/to/repo/.hg/hgignore
```

If you have multiple local ignore files then you can write

```
[ui]
ignore.first = /path/to/repo/.hg/firstignore
ignore.second = /path/to/repo/.hg/secondignore
```

Additional global ignore files can be configured in this way:

```
[ui]
ignore.first = /path/to/repo/.hg/firstignore
ignore.second = /path/to/repo/.hg/secondignore
ignore.third = ~/thirdignore
```

All settings live in `hgrc` file.  More details here:

- `hgrc` file location: [doc](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#files)
- `ui.ignore` setting reference: [doc](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#ui)
- about `.hgignore` files: [doc](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html)
- original recipe: [Tips And Tricks](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Ignore_files_in_local_working_copy_only)